# using the find_if() function in c++

Tags: c++

I get errors where i use the find_if function. It says no matching function. I did find that others have come through this error, but i couldn't quite understand the replies. Please can some one correct this & explain what the mistakes are? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
//Another way to split strings

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::istream;

istream& getWords(istream&, vector<string>&);
string& removeDelimeters(string&);
bool space(char);
bool not_space(char);
void display(const vector<string>&);

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;

    getWords(cin,words);
    display(words);

    return 0;
}

void display(const vector<string>& vec)
{
    cout<<endl;
    for(vector<string>::const_iterator iter = vec.begin();iter != vec.end();iter++)
    {
        cout<<*iter<<endl;
    }
}

bool space(char c)
{
    return isspace(c);
}

bool not_space(char c)
{
    return !isspace(c);
}

string& removeDelimeters(string& word)
{
    string delim = ",.`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}][:';?><|";

    for(unsigned int i = 0;i<word.size();i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0;j<delim.size();j++)
        {
            if(word[i] == delim[j])
            {
                word.erase(word.begin()+i);     //removes the value at the given index
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return word;
}

istream& getWords(istream& in, vector<string>& vec)
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;

    string initial;

    cout<<"Enter your initial sentance : ";
    getline(cin,initial);

    initial = removeDelimeters(initial);

    iter i = initial.begin();
    while(i != initial.end())
    {
        //ignore leading blanks
        i = find_if(i,initial.end(),not_space);

        //find the end of the word
        iter j = find_if(j,initial.end(),space);

        //copy the characters in [i,j)
        if(i != initial.end())
        {
            vec.push_back(string(i,j));
        }

        i = j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the `using std::find_if` as mentioned by John Dibling, and a whole host of other issues (look at `getWords` method and what it's doing with the passed in stream, and return type? etc.)

Your main problem is that you are passing in two *different iterator types* to `find_if`, the first iterator is a `const_iterator` - because you assign to a `const_iterator`, but the second iterator is non const, i.e. `initial.begin()` - because `initial` is not const - and the const/non const iterators are different types, which is why it won't find `find_if` to match...

Comment: Ah, I changed the typedef to `string::iterator` and the `find_if` errors went away. And I didn't use `std::` or `using std::find_if;`. So I think that supports my argument about ADL.

Comment: Hey, ya it made the errors go away. Yes, i think i understand the mistakes. I'm a student trying to climb the ladder of life, so i'm really grateful to the people who explained this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the `std` namespace:

```
iter j = std::find_if(j,initial.end(),space);
```

Or do what you did above, and add a `using` declaration:

`using std::find_if;`

Comment: @OP, also, note the issue with that particular line, you are passing in `j` as the starting iterator.. presumably you meant `i`?

Comment: But the iterators are in the `std` namespace, so wouldn't ADL pick up `std::find_if`?

Comment: @Nim +1.  I didn't even really look at the code.  Figured there was a 89.7% chance that OP was missing `std` and stopped looking after I found that

Comment: @Fred:  No, how could ADL pick up `find_if`?  It found the iterators because `iter` was `typedef`-ed to `string::const_iterator` and there is a `using std::string`

Comment: @John: Well, I just tried it and adding `std::` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Fred: I beg to differ.  There are other problems to be sure, like ambigious template parameter resolution, but the problem of finding `find_if` is definitely fixed.

Comment: @John: I copied and pasted the above code and tried both `std::find_if` and `using std::find_if;`. It made no difference at all in the errors I got.

Comment: @John: `testADL.cpp:85: error: no matching function for call to âfind_if(getWords(std::istream&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)::iter&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, bool (&)(char))`

Comment: @John: (continued) `testADL.cpp:88: error: no matching function for call to âfind_if(getWords(std::istream&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)::iter&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, bool (&)(char))`

Comment: @Fred: I think you're having more a problem with parameter type mismatch now, not the compiler not being able to find `std::find_if`.  See @Nim's response

Comment: @John: I agree. And that's the OP's problem too, not the namespace issue.